# Изображение стало поверх текста, как опустить текст?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть код:

```
<a href="">
    <div id="fon1" class="fon1">
        <img src="/images/fon/2.jpg" id="img_1" style="position: absolute;">
        <img src="/images/fon/3.jpg" id="img_2" style="opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity=0); position: absolute;">
        <img src="/images/fon/5.jpg" id="img_3" style="opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity=0); position: absolute;">
        <for>Текст1</for>
        <for1>Текст2</for1>
    </div>
</a>
```

Как видите, он включает в себя `img`. В `css` всё прописано к ним:

```
.fon1 > img {
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    width: 356px;
    height: 290px;
}
```

И есть `JS`, который меняет картинки как слайд-шоу.

```
var image_count = 3;
var interval = 10000;
var time_out = 5;
var i = 0;
var timeout;
var opacity = 100;

function change_image() {
    opacity--;
    var j = i + 1;
    var current_image = 'img_' + i;
    if (i == image_count) j = 1;
    var next_image = 'img_' + j;
    document.getElementById(current_image).style.opacity = opacity / 100;
    document.getElementById(current_image).style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + opacity + ')';
    document.getElementById(next_image).style.opacity = (100 - opacity) / 100;
    document.getElementById(next_image).style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + (100 - opacity) + ')';
    timeout = setTimeout('change_image()', time_out);
    if (opacity == 1) {
        opacity = 100;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
}

setInterval(function () {
    i++;
    if (i > image_count) i = 1;
    change_image();
}, interval);
```

И как только я подключил скрипт, всё работает отлично, но текст почему-то стал находиться под ним и его не видно. А раньше он был внизу изображения. Подскажите в чём здесь может быть ошибка? Не могу понять никак.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот исправленный пример вашего кода:

```js
var image_count = 3;
var interval = 10000;
var time_out = 5;
var i = 0;
var timeout;
var opacity = 100;

function change_image() {
 opacity--;
 var j = i + 1;
 var current_image = 'img_' + i;
 if (i == image_count) j = 1;
 var next_image = 'img_' + j;
 document.getElementById(current_image).style.opacity=opacity/100;
 document.getElementById(current_image).style.filter='alpha(opacity='+opacity+')';
 document.getElementById(next_image).style.opacity=(100-opacity)/100;
 document.getElementById(next_image).style.filter='alpha(opacity='+(100-opacity)+')';
 timeout = setTimeout("change_image()", time_out);
 if (opacity==1) {
  opacity = 100;
  clearTimeout(timeout);
 }
}

setInterval (function() {i++; if (i>image_count) i=1; change_image();}, interval);
```

```css
.fon1>img {   
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    width: 356px;
    height: 290px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
           <a href="">
                <div id="fon1" class="fon1">
                    <img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/gweb-uniblog-publish-prod/static/blog/images/google-200x200.7714256da16f.png" id="img_1" style="position: absolute;">
                    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b2/Google_tv_logo.svg/1200px-Google_tv_logo.svg.png" id="img_2" style="opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity=0);
position: absolute;">
                    <img src="https://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2011/08/google-tv-logo.jpg" id="img_3" style="opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity=0);
position: absolute;">
                    <for>Текст1</for>               
                    <for1>Текст2</for1>
                </div>
            </a>
```

Обясняю кратко вашу ошибку. Дело в том что во время работы вашего скрипта для слайдера вы поставляете атрибут для картинок `position: absolute`, и обсалютно позиционированные элементы не игнорируються элементами со свойством `position: static`; Эти элементы не как будто не существуют друг для друга, и обе постовляються в левого верхнего угла и накрывают друг друга. Подробнее об этом можете прочитать [тут](http://htmlbook.ru/css/position).

Comment: Насколько я вижу вы только добавили " margin-top: 30px;"?

Comment: Да, вы хотели узнать почему так бывает и исправить, я исправил, и при этом обяснил почему так было

Comment: Я просто к тому, что значит единственный выход использовать margin-top?

Comment: @user250973 нет это один из многих

Comment: спасибо, тогда буду использовать margin-top

Comment: @user250973 Вообще то если создаете элемент с позицией `absolute` , то грамотно что бы у него был родитель с позиционированием `relative`.

Answer (score 0):

смотри CSS

И посмотри как сделано в JavasScript, может все таки использовать этот код?

```js
;(function(){
 var change_image = function() {

   if (j == childrens.length) {
    j = 0;
   }

   if (i == childrens.length) {
    i = 0;
   }

   childrens[i].style.opacity = 0;
   childrens[i].style.filter = 'alpha(opacity = 0)';
   childrens[j].style.opacity = 1;
   childrens[j].style.filter='alpha(opacity = 1)';
   link.href = childrens[j].dataset.url || '#';
   i++;
   j++;
};

var childrens = document.querySelectorAll('.fon1 > img'),
    link = document.getElementById('link'),
    interval = 5,
    i = 0,
    j = 1;
 
childrens[0].style.opacity = 1;
link.href = childrens[0].dataset.url || '#';

setInterval(function(){
 change_image();
}, interval * 1000);
})();
```

```css
.fon1 > img {
 opacity: 0;
 transition: 0.5s;
 position: absolute;
 border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
 width: 356px;
 height: 290px;
 z-index: 1;
}
.fon1 > span {
 position: relative;
    top: 12px;
 left: 12px;
 z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<a id="link" target="_blank" href="">
   <div id="fon1" class="fon1">
     <img data-url="http://mysite1.ru" alt src="http://slidervilla.com/smooth-slider/files/2014/05/3.jpg" />
     <img data-url="http://mysite2.ru" alt src="http://demo.smartaddons.com/extensions/joomla17/cache/mod_sj_content_slider/cc021ca251f443c4a934cba184872eff.jpeg" />
     <img data-url="http://mysite3.ru" alt src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xebpM_-GwG0/maxresdefault.jpg" />
     <span>Текст1</span>               
     <span>Текст2</span>
   </div>
</a>
```